# how we can find div in datalist

Tags: asp.net

in my data list i have a  (div) and it's id is divpost and it's visibility is false. now i like to find that in datalist_databound and if condition is ok visibility will be true.

so i have used below code, but i do not know how i have to find (divpost).

for finding lables or another controls i have no problem according to below code, but for div i do not know how?

```
 protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound
 (object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{


  var x = (Guid)(DataList1.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]);
    Label labelstatus = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblstatus");
    Label labelcomment = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblcomment");
    BindLable(labelstatus,labelcomment, x);


    var q3 = (from s in _DataContext.tblSends


              where (s.DraftId == _Draftid) 

              select s.ToEmailId ).Distinct();


    if ((Guid)q3.SingleOrDefault() == (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
    {
        divpostcomment.visible = true;
    }
```

aspx markup is like below:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="userid" 
    OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" 
    >
    <SeparatorStyle BorderStyle="Dotted" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="style2">
            <tr>
                <td>

                   <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# "comments from "+Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

                    <div id="divPostComment" runat="server" visible="false">

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" />
                        <asp:Button ID="pstComment" runat="server" Text="Post Comment" />

                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>



                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Control theDiv = e.Item.FindControl("divPostComment");
if (theDiv != null) theDiv.Visible = true;
```